# Why won't this simple SVG line display in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, svg

This simple SVG will display (a fat line) in FF, but will display nothing in Chrome (tried it on v58.0.3029.110 on Linux).

Why is this happening?

Is SVG buggy in browsers, in general? I'm trying to create a simple charting library, but if I get such erratic behaviour, I don't know what I should do.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Works on FF, doesn't work on Chrome</title>
</head>
<body>

<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="-1 1.007230, 2 0.000840" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border: 1px solid blue;">

  <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="1.0073" y2="1.008" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" />

</svg>


</body>
</html>
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="-1 1.007230, 2 0.000840" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
    
      <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="1.0073" y2="1.008" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" />
      
    </svg>
```

Comment: Does not work on IE11 and Edge (Windows 10) either.

Comment: Probably best to avoid small numbers for viewBox sizes